# MobileFirst 7.1: no registered challenge handler with key wl_sessionIndependentSupport

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I encounter this error on the console logs of an iPad hybrid app built on MobileFirst Platform 7.1, when using `WL.Client.connect()`:

```
2017-03-14 01:45:34.552 myApp[37732:5685087]
[ERROR] [WL_REQUEST] __43-[WLRequest processFailuresWithDictionary:]_block_invoke in WLRequest.m:694 :: 
Challenge handler does not exist. There is no registered challenge handler with key wl_sessionIndependentSupport
```

It seems, however, `wl_sessionIndependentSupport` is not documented anywhere, so I have no clue on how to solve this error.

Our server is configured for session-independent mode, but I am not aware of it requiring any client-side changes.(See [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_overview_session_indep.html#overview_of_ibm_java_adaps__coding%20)), for example).

Comment: Please take a look at your server log at the time that this client log was captured and see if you see a message with a string similar to "This client is not supported in session independent mode".  It looks like your client is attempting to access a protected resource, but for some reason is seen as not supporting session-independent mode.

If you can find the reference in the server log, please set your server's trace specification to "com.ibm.worklight.*=all:com.worklight.*=all:com.ibm.mfp.*=all:*=info" then recreate the issue and post the trace here.

Comment: Hi John, the error did not happen anymore after reinstalling mobile app so... not sure how to reproduce...